# How to highlight specific text in RED within a cell using VBA function

Tags: excel

There is a column with employee restriction codes with dates and commas to include multiple restrictions. These cells will contain small string of text and others will have a large amount of text. I want to highlight in RED a particular value. I do not want to startchar, I want to highlight exact values in RED. I want to highlight exact values of RDTN, and RDAN. I cannot use startchar due to these certain codes will be anywhere within the sting of data in each cell.

I have the following but I need to adjust the startchar to highlight anything RDTN anywhere in a cell RED

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Dim startchar As Integer

For i=2 To 21500
With Sheets(“sheet1”).Cells(i, 5)
startchar = InStr(1, .Value, “RDTN”)
If startchar <> 0 Then
Lencolor = Len(.Value) - startchar + 1
.Characters(Start:=startchar, Length:=Length:=Lencolor).Font.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
End If
End With

Next i

End Sub

NOTE:::: i want to highlight RDTN anywhere in the cell mixed in with a large amount of other text.

Comment: There has to be something missing in your code.  As is, it would not compile.

Answer (score 0):

This line takes the 2nd character of the active cell and turns it red:

```
ActiveCell.Characters(Start:=2, Length:=1).Font.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
```

You can of course do it with any cell, not just the active one and tweak `Start`, `Length` and the color to achieve the desired result.